# Independence of two scaled multivariate normals

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

I was given the following question as a practice question for an exam:

> Let $X \sim N_k\left(\mu,\Sigma\right)$. For (deterministic) $l \times k$ matrix $A$ and $m \times k$ matrix $B$, show that $AX$ and $BX$ are independent iff $A\Sigma B^T$ is a matrix of zero entries.

To prove the if part, I assumed their independence and then proceeded to look at the conditional covariance of $BX$ given $AX = a$, where $a$ is an $l$ vector.

When I do this, after all my simplifications, I end up with $B\Sigma B^T - B\Sigma B^T = 0$.

**Question:** What am I supposed to end up with as my solution for $\operatorname{Cov}\left(BX|AX = a\right)$?

Any help with this and the converse would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because it's a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag to your question. Please take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Where are you starting from? For instance, if you may assume that (1) linear combinations of a multivariate Normal are multivariate Normal and (2) two Normal variables are independent when they have zero covariance, then this result follows immediately upon recognizing that $A\Sigma B^\prime$ is the matrix of covariances between $AX$ and $BX$. So, which of these preliminary results needs demonstration?

Comment: @whuber I am assuming (1) and (2). What confuses me is that in the covariance matrix, I have $A\Sigma B^T$ and $B\Sigma A^T$, so why is it that only the former needs all zero entries? Or am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Yes, you are: because $\Sigma=\Sigma^\prime$, $A\Sigma B^\prime$ and $B\Sigma A^\prime$ are transposes of each other, whence one is zero if and only if the other is.